# Precalculus (Functions) If $f(2x+\frac{y}{8}, 2x-\frac{y}{8}) = xy, $ then $f(m,n) +f(n,m)=0$ only when :

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f(2x+\frac{y}{8}, 2x-\frac{y}{8}) = xy, $ then $f(m,n) +f(n,m)=0 $

Options are :

(a) only when $m =n$

(b)  only when $m \neq n$

(c) only when $m =-n$

(d) for all $m$ and $n$

My approach :

$x=0, y =0 \Rightarrow f(0 , 0) =0 ; $ By putting $x = 1, y = 1$  gives $f(\frac{17}{8}, \frac{15}{8})$ = 1

Is it the right way please suggest... thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $2x+y/8=m,~~~2x-y/8=n$, so by solving two equations with respect to $x$ and $y$, you have $$x=\frac{m+n}4,~~~y=4(m-n)$$ Hence $f(m,n)=xy=m^2-n^2$ so $$f(m,n)+f(n,m)=0, ~~\forall m,n$$ The following codes are while working with Maple:

```
 > d:=solve({m=2x+y/8,n=2x-y/8},{x,y}):
 > f:=(x,y)->x*y:
 > simplify(subs({d[1],d[2]},f(x,y)));
                                   m^2-n^2
```

Comment: From where can  I get this maple.. please suggest.. thanks for your answer..

Comment: @sultan: From this [site](http://www.maplesoft.com/products/maple/).

Comment: @amWhy: I am busy for finalizing the paper. :(

Comment: I'd love to read your paper when you're finished, and will be happy to proof-read, if you'd like me to! :-)